# can't delete dynamic array from class

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, memory-leaks

```
Vector& Vector::operator=(const Vector& other)
{
    int i = 0;

    delete[] this->_elements; // this line is bad !

    // copying all the fields:
    this->_size = other._size;
    this->_capacity = other._capacity;
    this->_resizeFactor = other._resizeFactor;

    this->_elements = new int[other._capacity]; // allocating new memory for the array.

    for (i = 0; i < this->_capacity; i++) // copying the array's.
    {
        this->_elements[i] = other._elements[i];
    }

    return *this;
}
```

I am trying to implement the '=' operator to deep copy objects, when I am trying to delete the old array I get this problem:
[image]

I can delete this line and all will works fine but then I will have a memory leaks.

Comment: The only way that `delete[]` statement can fail is if either `this` or `_elements` is a bad pointer to begin with. So either you are calling `operator=` on a bad `Vector` object, or you are not managing `_elements` correctly elsewhere in your code. Neither of which we can diagnose with this limited snippet. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] demonstrating the failure in action.

Comment: You should protect against self assignment: `if (this = &other) { return *this; }`

Comment: thank you!, but still I have to remove this array because then I will have a memory leaks.

Comment: and when I am trying to delete I get ^ this ^ error.

Comment: @Jarod42 `this = &other` is an assignment. `this == &other` is a comparison.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `_free_dbg` also may fail if a write outside of bounds for dynamically allocated array had happened or a `delete` where a `delete[]` was needed anywhere in program prior to this call. Something similar may happen in GNU chain as well, those bugs are infuriating to find.

Comment: Did you initial this int pointer "elements" in every constructor Vector::Vector(....)?